# Creating custom push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing a custom segue class (`HySegue`) which allows views to animate the transition. The code is working great, except when under a `UINavigationController` stack. Actually, the transitions run and animate well, but the top `UINavigationBar` is what is causing me problems.

When first animating, I add the destination view as a subview of the source view. As such:

```
    UIView * sourceView = sourceViewController.view;
    UIView * destinationView = viewControllerToPresent.view;

    // Force the source view to layout
    [sourceView addSubview:destinationView];
    [sourceView layoutIfNeeded];
```

When the transition is over, I present the destination view controller:

```
    UIViewController * parentViewController = viewControllerToDismiss.parentViewController;
    UIView * destinationView = destinationViewController.view;

    // Break the view hierarchy that was setup earlier
    [destinationView removeFromSuperview];

    // When presenting in a UINavigationController stack, push the destination view controller
    if ([parentViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        [(UINavigationController *)parentViewController pushViewController:destinationViewController
                                                                  animated:NO];
    }

    else {

        // Present the destination view controller
        [viewControllerToDismiss presentViewController:destinationViewController
                                              animated:NO
                                            completion:nil];

        [viewControllerToDismiss willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [viewControllerToDismiss.view removeFromSuperview];
        [viewControllerToDismiss removeFromParentViewController];
        [viewControllerToDismiss didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    }
```

The problem is that during the animation the destination view does not know that it's being pushed in a navigation stack and so the top bar, although visible, is not taken into account in the view's bounds. That is, the navigation bar is visible because it's visible for the source view controller, but the destination view controller knows nothing about it. When the animation finishes the destination view controller is pushed onto the stack, so it now knows about the navigation bar, and all my content with Top Space to Top Layout Guides constraints jumps down on the frame.

The top bar also doesn't show in IB. This is when I use my custom segue:

[image]

And this is when I use `show` segue:

[image]

Notice that the bar shows on the later but not on the former.

What I was wondering is how IB knows that it's a push segue. Is it some flag? Is it because of the specific class it's using? How would I make my custom segue also a push segue?

Edit: I loved the segue's type in `prepareForSegue:sender:` and it seems its type is `UIStoryboardPushSegue`, which is not a public or documented class. How can I can I solve it then? I already tried setting the destination view's `frame` and `bounds` from the source view.

Comment: Did you set the destination controller's view's frame to the source view's bounds? I think that should work.

Comment: If the source view controller is set to have its view "under top bars", then its frame will be full screen height, so I guess that's why that doesn't work. If you set edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone, and then do what I said above, does it work?

Comment: Just tried, but it doesn't work. Now not only do the UI elements jump, but I have a black top bar, because my top bar is transparent.